# How do you perform joins of two KeyValueRDD with Key is a Tuple in Spark using Python?

Tags: python, apache-spark, rdd

How would you perform joins KeyValueRDD in Apache Spark using python?

This is my two RDD

```
rddUser:[((u'M', '[68-73]', u'B'), u'TwoFace'), ((u'F', '[33-38]', u'Fr'), u'Catwoman'), ((u'Female', '[23-28]', u'L'), u'HarleyQuinn'), ((u'M', '[75+]', u'L'), u'Joker'), ((u'F', '[28-33]', u'Belgium'), u'PoisonIvy')]
rdd:[((u'F', '[23-28]', u'L'), 180.0), ((u'F', '[28-33]', u'B'), 60.0), ((u'F', '[33-38]', u'Fr'), 56.0), ((u'M', '[68-73]', u'B'), 136.0), ((u'M', '[75+]', u'L'), 98.0)]
```

I have Try this :

```
print rddUser.join(rdd).collect()
```

but Spark block in this line

Expected Result (or something like that):

```
((u'M', '[68-73]', u'B'), u'TwoFace', 136.0)
```

How can i make that ?

**Edit :**

> It works fine in pyspark, but when i use it in my script, the script wait at the line. After 30 min, this log show up :

```
17/04/27 12:25:22 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_2_piece0 on 192.168.2.76:40028 in memory (size: 11.8 KB, free: 366.3 MB)
17/04/27 12:25:22 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_3_piece0 on 192.168.2.76:40028 in memory (size: 5.8 KB, free: 366.3 MB)
17/04/27 12:25:22 INFO ContextCleaner: Cleaned accumulator 135
17/04/27 12:25:22 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_4_piece0 on 192.168.2.76:40028 in memory (size: 10.7 KB, free: 366.3 MB)
17/04/27 12:25:22 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_5_piece0 on 192.168.2.76:40028 in memory (size: 399.0 B, free: 366.3 MB)
17/04/27 12:25:22 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_6_piece0 on 192.168.2.76:40028 in memory (size: 9.5 KB, free: 366.3 MB)
17/04/27 12:25:22 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_7_piece0 on 192.168.2.76:40028 in memory (size: 5.0 KB, free: 366.3 MB)
```

> After 1h30, nothing append

Comment: How are you submitting spark job. Please provide full spark-submit arguments you used

Answer (score 0):

Join works just fine in `pyspark` , however, with your current data it will create joined result which will be of format (k, (v1,v2))  rather than (k,v1,v2) which you are expecting. You can do a `map` to change it however you want.

Below is working just fine for me -

```
rddUser = sc.parallelize([((u'M', '[68-73]', u'B'), u'TwoFace'), 
                          ((u'F', '[33-38]', u'Fr'), u'Catwoman'), 
                          ((u'Female', '[23-28]', u'L'), u'HarleyQuinn'), 
                          ((u'M', '[75+]', u'L'), u'Joker'), 
                          ((u'F', '[28-33]', u'Belgium'), u'PoisonIvy')])

rdd =sc.parallelize([((u'F', '[23-28]', u'L'), 180.0), 
                     ((u'F', '[28-33]', u'B'), 60.0), 
                     ((u'F', '[33-38]', u'Fr'), 56.0), 
                     ((u'M', '[68-73]', u'B'), 136.0), 
                     ((u'M', '[75+]', u'L'), 98.0)])

rddUser.join(rdd).collect()
```

output :

```
[(('M', '[68-73]', 'B'), ('TwoFace', 136.0)),
 (('F', '[33-38]', 'Fr'), ('Catwoman', 56.0)),
 (('M', '[75+]', 'L'), ('Joker', 98.0))]
```